# Is it possible to do hot gas filtration through fluidized bed reactors

Tags: mechanical-engineering, chemical-engineering, heat-exchanger, fluid-filtration

I am working on flue gas filtration and HCl gas is to be removed from the gas. I am wondering if a fluidized bed reactor could be used to filter the gas. The problem is, a furnace is used to provide the required heat to carry out this reaction, is it possible to use the already hot gases to perform a reaction instead of using the furnace?

Comment: Fluidized beds are not filters ; if they retained any solid they would plug up. In cat cracking they collect carbon but it is continuously burned off in the regeneration fluid bed.

Comment: Only if the gasses are as readily available as the furnace can produce.  You'll likely find that it is not, and can maybe used to preheat air fed to furnace.